# Alternative to Ctrl+' for Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I've installed latest sublime text 2 version today. I cannot make Control + ` work on 2 different PCs one on Windows 7 the other on Windows 8.1.

In the past I remember it did work.

So what's the alternative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in *Preferences/Key Bindings -- User* and modify the shortcut to something that will work:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+`"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "console", "toggle": true} },
```

By the way: isn't it possible that the second PC has different keyboard layout or that some program is globally overriding that shortcut? As far as I know this keybinding was not changed.

Comment: Is it normal that it was empty ? I added your stuff except I have to change to ' and delete , at the end but still does not work.

Comment: @user310291 Glad to hear it. By the way it is normal that the file is empty by default. It contains user overrides for the default keybindings (which can be found in preferences / keybindings - default).